# DevEco cannot connect HonorX10 on HarmonyOS3.0

Tags: harmonyos, deveco-studio

DevEco Studio 4.0Beta2 IDE, my phone is HonorX10 on HarmonyOS3.0.
I use `adb devices` command to see that:

```
List of devices attached
H5X6R20618000205        device
```

but when I use `hdc list` command it give me this:

```
No any target
```

I've tried so many ways as the official site guide and blog, but nothing got, just the same `No Devices`.
Is there any one who can give me some advices or the solution for the problem? thanks~